# How to create a folder with a folder name containing spaces in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, directory, command, mkdir

How to create a folder witha a folder name containing spaces in linux?

For Example, folder name should be "Stack OverFlow".

Comment: is there any problem with the answers? You seem to be accepting and unaccepting them. Feel free to add a comment if you need clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also do `mkdir Stack\ OverFlow` the `\` does the same thing as `" "` but it is easier. so you can do stuff like `mkdir Stack\ OverFlow\ is\ Great`. you can manipulate that folder using the `\` as well. so things like `cd Stack\ OverFlow` and `rm -rf Stack\ OverFlow`.

Comment: What about File names ?

Comment: you create them the same way, but instead of "mkdir" you would use "touch". for example, "touch hello\ world.txt" this would create "hello world.txt" file. :)

Comment: But when we make folders/files with this command, and if we do `ls`, then the file created shown like this `'new folder'` (i.e, with single quotes at beginning and end of folders/file name), Is their a way to avoid single quotes when creating folder/files name with space?

Comment: this is answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551965/why-is-my-directory-getting-quotes-around-it-when-created)

Answer (score 2):

Just use quotes around the name:

```
mkdir "this is my dir"
```

Then you can check it by also using quotes:

```
$ ls -ld "this is my dir"
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 4096 Aug 17 11:59 this is my dir
```

Comment: Well this is false, because both of them do the same. Good to know that this is a revenge for [my comment in your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39017077/1983854). In general, when programming, is good not to take things personally. Cheers