# shell command to delete range of characters from a line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has one single line of 50 characters. I want to delete character 12 to 17 and character 33 to 44 using any shell command. Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: since you tagged with awk and sed you may have tried something already. Please [edit] your question to show them, as well as provide a [mcve]. It would be good to check [ask] as well. Welcome to [so]!

Comment: Take a look at `cut`'s option `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cut removes sections from each line of files. From `man cut`:

> -c
>    specifies a range of characters
>
> --complement
>     complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields

this can be help to print from first to 11th character, from 18th to 32th and from 45th to the end:

```
cut -c -11,18-32,45- yourFile
```

or

```
cut -c 12-17,33-44 text --complement yourFile
```

Comment: what is the point of posting two commands that do the opposite without any kind of explanation?

Comment: No need to [downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993454/how-to-create-a-folder-with-a-folder-name-containing-spaces-in-linux/38993474?noredirect=1#comment65386150_38993474) on revenge, by the way.

Comment: undownvoting since this already contains some explanation. It would benefit from an example, though

Comment: cut -c -11,18-32,45- yourFile this worked for me. Thank you very much